# SQLDescribeCol giving different column size on two different machine?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

SQLDescribeCol method used to know the column size in table. but in one column the datatype is text its giving size 8190 and other machine its giving 65535. Please tell me why its happening?

I need to change means some setting  is required in my system.

Database Name PostgreSql 8.4
Machine Redhat Linux 64 bit
Column Datatype is Text

I am Calling this method  **sqldescribecol** to know the Size of column

please tell me if u know

Thanks in Advance......

Hanish

Comment: Database Name PostgreSql 8.4  Column Datatype text I am calling this method directly SqlDescribCol and Redhat Linux machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a difference in ODBC version or configuration.  Look for a setting for Unknown Sizes in the ODBC configuration.

Comment: Hi Kgrittn Thanks for Reply,Yes This is ODBC Version Problem but how i will change the size for text datatype i read from net someone told me add this line in odbcfile textasLongvarchar=yes but its decrease the size to 255 but i want size 65535 so i want to know where i will add this size.

Comment: You might want to add the "odbc" tag to your question; while I know a lot about PostgreSQL and was therefore alerted to this question, I don't know much about ODBC.  You might check here: http://psqlodbc.projects.postgresql.org/

Comment: For the record here, please describe the solution.